# Why are Username and Password are no longer accepted for Outbound GMail?

Tags: email

We use GMail (G-Suite) for outbound mail. Three days ago, we started getting:

authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 535, response: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials n3sm11135782pff.102 - gsmtp)]

We've verified (ad nauseam) that the Username and Password are correct. We can use them to send and receive through GMail just fine. However, we can no longer send with Outlook, either.

How can I find out why the Username and Password are no longer accepted?

Comment: Can you confirm that it's not the issue described here? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/28609/12  I realize this doesn't account for Outlook but it's good to rule out.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion (I never would have thought of that on my own) but, we can rule it out. Both are using php 7.2.22.

Answer (score 3):

This link seems to fix things, if only temporarily: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha